# NSData methods equivalent in Java

Tags: java, android, swift, nsdata, bytebuffer

I am trying to match iOS code to Java code, and I run into the problem. I read all the answers and as far as I understood I need to use **ByteBuffer** as an equivalent to **NSData** in Swift.
But I couldn't find the methods that will help me to achieve this logic.

1. In Java I need to initializes an object filled with a given number of bytes copied from a given buffer, like in this code
   `let data = NSData(bytes: array, length: 4)`
2. As a second step I need to get a copy a number of bytes from the start of the data object into a given buffer, like in this array.
   `data.getBytes(&value, length: 4).`

Will appreciate any help.

Comment: In java you'd need to declare data as like `byte[] data`, but how do you get bytes from `array` really depends on what `array` is. For example a single `int` would be converted like this: `byte[] data = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(myInt).array()`
And for second question, you'd do `Arrays.copyOfRange(` I think. My Java is very rusty, I may be wrong.

Comment: @sfgblackwarkrts the  ```array``` it is a byte array.